# xpath3 issue in mule

Tags: xpath, mule, mule-component

Here is my incoming payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <detail><ns1:SiperianRequestFault xmlns:ns1="urn:siperian.api">
    <ns1:requestName>SearchQuery</ns1:requestName>
    <ns1:errorCode>SIP-18018</ns1:errorCode>
    <ns1:errorMessage>SIP-18018: Request not recognized by the user profile providers.
Review the server log for more details.</ns1:errorMessage>
</ns1:SiperianRequestFault></detail>
```

when I query for

`xpath3('//detail')`

here is the output

```
SearchQuerySIP-18018SIP-18018: Request not recognized by the user profile providers.Review the server log for more details.
```

But what I want is to extract the `errorCode, errorMessage` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `#[xpath3('/detail/*:SiperianRequestFault/*:errorCode')]` to get errorCode. I have used `*:` for defining namespace wildcard. If you want to use namespace you can define it as

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
   <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns1" uri="urn:siperian.api" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

then expression will be like `#[xpath3('/detail/ns1:SiperianRequestFault/ns1:errorCode')]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much bro!!